# Why is col-sm-* applying to xs screens?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap for a project, and I am using different column widths for xs, sm, and md screens. When I apply col-xs-* and col-md-* , the columns resize perfectly for xs, md, and lg screens. When I add col-sm-*, the columns resize perfectly for sm, md, and lg, but I lose the xs configuration and it's replaced with the sm layout.

Can anyone help me out? How can I keep the xs layout along with the sm layout?

```
    <div class="container-fluid main-content text-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10">
          ...
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
              ...
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
              ...
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 latest-headlines">
          ...
          <div class="more-news-button">
            ...
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you are using a custom version of bootstrap? If so, I'd try the original version first.

Comment: What is your Bootstrap version?

Answer (score 3):

It is Boostrap 3.4.1. It turns out the problem was I didn't have this line in the head. This solved it!

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```